# How to temporarily connect to MySQL in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to connect to `MySQL` in `MapReduce` temporarily. In other words, I want to bring table in MySQL to Map function temporarily to change `InputData(Text)` but, the Result was empty.

Below is my code:

```
public class Map extends Mapper{

private Text outputKey=new Text();

private final static IntWritable outputValue=new IntWritable(1);

public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context)
throws IOException,InterruptedException
{
    int i=0;
    try{
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://locallhost:3306/test_db",
                "user","user");
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from studentinfo");
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
            i++;

        AirlinePerformanceParser parser=new AirlinePerformanceParser(value);
        outputKey.set(parser.getMonth_day()+","+i);
        context.write(outputKey, outputValue);

    }catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Map and reduce work well (there are no exceptions), but Result was empty.

I don't want to use `DBInputFormat`. MySQL table must not be used by `DBInputFormat`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Is table `studentinfo` is in database?

Comment: Once you are inside Mapper, the program to connect MySQL is just like any other main method, unless you want some optimization. Please unit test the following code and verify, if the data is coming properly from database                                                                            **"jdbc:sqlserver://locallhost:3306/test_db","user","user"
"select * from studentinfo"**    . is this "jdbc:sqlserver" correct. I think it should be "jdbc:mysql". And make sure test_db database is present with "studentinfo" table

Answer (score 0):

If your query is static, i.e.it does not depend on map input (as is your current query), you should move your sql code into the setup function, to query your DB only once.

```
// set global the data buffer from your sql results (here a counter)
int nbResults;

@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // query your DB
    Connection con [...]
 }

public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException {
    AirlinePerformanceParser parser=new AirlinePerformanceParser(value);
    outputKey.set(parser.getMonth_day()+","+nbResults);
    context.write(outputKey, outputValue);
}
```

As pointed by @Ramzy, check the connexion status.

In addition, do not perform a `SELECT *` if what you need is a `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and I have more question. Would you mind if I ask why I must use setup function? why Query does not work in map function? Thanks!

Comment: The `setup` method is called once automatically. Therefore, if you have a common procedure to retrieve data for all the mappers, yo may consider to execute it in there.

Comment: The query does not work because the JDBC connexion should be wrong, I have a doubt on `localhost`

Comment: oh really thanks. I aleady fix 'localhost' and suceed to connect JDBC I really appreciate your help!